# Automatic including xfig figures (.xfig) in PDFLatex, similarly as EPSTOPDF

Tags: pdftex, eps, epstopdf

Would you know a method for including xfig figures (.xfig) in PDFLatex, similarly as EPSTOPDF?

my example xfig file (test.xfig) is:

```
#FIG 3.2  Produced by xfig version 3.2.6a
Landscape
Center
Metric
A4
100.00
Single
-2
1200 2
2 2 0 1 0 7 50 -1 -1 0.000 0 0 -1 0 0 5
  810 810 3465 810 3465 2385 810 2385 810 810
2 2 0 1 0 7 50 -1 -1 0.000 0 0 -1 0 0 5
  2430 1215 5265 1215 5265 3105 2430 3105 2430 1215
2 2 0 1 0 7 50 -1 -1 0.000 0 0 -1 0 0 5
  1125 1530 4140 1530 4140 3600 1125 3600 1125 1530
4 0 0 50 -1 0 12 0.0000 4 135 2070 1440 3060 Hello Latex Under Linux\001
```

For EPS, it can be done under Linux with (an heavy GS (ghostscript) installed). Ideally would be a xfigtopdf to do same thing.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
{\bfseries Minimal Example To Import EPS In PDFLATEX}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{hellolatex.eps}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I am surprised that there is nothing for XFIG since EPS and XFIG are the most common file formats, used by expert scientists (veterans).

Comment: Would you mind explaining what your question is a bit better? You present a code that allows you to include eps files in a document that you process with `pdflatex`, right? And what you want to have is some package that allows you to include xfig figures while again processing with `pdflatex`, correct? Are you aware of [fig2tikz](http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/software/figpy/fig2tikz)?

Comment: the idea would be to do same as for XFIG. I want to have xfig figures automatically into pdflatex, without having to export all the time. EPSTOPDF packages does that for EPS directly. likely a minimal fig2tikz might be of interest if it works as epstopdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with `fig2dev` (from the `transfig` package) and the `epstopdf` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xfig}
#FIG 3.2  Produced by xfig version 3.2.6a
Landscape
Center
Metric
A4
100.00
Single
-2
1200 2
2 2 0 1 0 7 50 -1 -1 0.000 0 0 -1 0 0 5
  810 810 3465 810 3465 2385 810 2385 810 810
2 2 0 1 0 7 50 -1 -1 0.000 0 0 -1 0 0 5
  2430 1215 5265 1215 5265 3105 2430 3105 2430 1215
2 2 0 1 0 7 50 -1 -1 0.000 0 0 -1 0 0 5
  1125 1530 4140 1530 4140 3600 1125 3600 1125 1530
4 0 0 50 -1 0 12 0.0000 4 135 2070 1440 3060 Hello Latex Under Linux\001
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

% add new rule to convert xfig to pdf
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.xfig}{pdf}{.pdf}{fig2dev -L pdf #1 \OutputFile}
% automatically search for xfig extension (optional)
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.xfig}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{\jobname.xfig}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the workaround  "\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.xfig}{pdf}{.pdf}{fig2dev -L pdf #1 \OutputFile}" works but it is highly dangerous and it could be endangering/crashing the computer. Furthermore, eps and xfig  shall  be separated and shall work well together.

Comment: How is it different to using epstopdf for an EPS file? And in not sure what you mean by the second sentence.

Comment: epstopdf shall be left as it is. Likely we should find a package that handles the xfig/fig figures, so that users can still see that their latex document can handle eps, xfig, png, .... as normally.

Comment: You *can* still handle EPS, PNG, etc. as normal. `\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule` *adds* a rule for XFIG. It doesn't replace the rule for EPS. Try it—you can still include an EPS in my above example. The `epstopdf` package allows you to add as many rules as you want for different file types. You could also adjust it to use `xfigtopdf` instead of `fig2dev` if you wanted. I don't have `xfigtopdf` so I used `fig2dev` which is in CTAN. This method is also no more dangerous than using `epstopdf` for EPS files. You still have to use the `--shell-escape` flag to call GhostScript as well.

Comment: Read section 1.6 of the `epstopdf` package manual. It says: "The support that package `epstopdf` implements is not limited to EPS files. Other image conversions can be declared."

Comment: my programmer feelings tells me that we should make a new package. those are unix rules of programming (authors of BSD). The more complex you will make a programme (or script) the more likely it will hang and not be stable. usepage{xfigtopdf} would be wisest, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69024/discussion-between-user98734-and-david-purton).